# Need help identifing links to capture on a website (Penetration testing)

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I got permission to do a University Meta data anaylsis project on a company a few days ago and I wanted to start testing today. I was working with a couple tools I have made in python using BeautifulSoup and realized none of them are working. They are going to the given URL opening it and then not spidering like they should. I went to the website and realized that they are not using `<a>` tags to specify links with a HREF, but they are using this

`<link rel="alternate" type="redacted" title="<redacted>" &raquo; ICal Feed" href="<link>`

What should I do to change this? To be honest I am not really sure what this line really is. I am well versed in python but not so much HTML.

This segment below is the code where I search for links to spider too. I then append them to a deque python object.

```
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

    #determine spidering links
    for anchor in soup.find_all("link"):
        link = anchor.attrs["href"] if "href" in anchor.attrs and anchor.attrs["href"].find("mailto") == -1 and anchor.attrs["href"].find("tel") == -1 and anchor.attrs["href"].find("#") == -1 else ''

        if link.startswith('/'):
            link = base_url + link
        elif not link.startswith('http'):
            link = path + link
        if not link in new_urls and not link in processed_urls and not link.find(start) == -1:
            new_urls.append(link)
```

Comment: did you redact the href or is there really no value associated with href attribute? Looks like you are expecting href to start with a specific substring potentially (or at the very least avoid starting with certain values)?

Comment: @QHarr I just redacted it!

Comment: Is there a string/s you expect hrefs to commence with?

Comment: @QHarr not specifically I just want links form the HTML so I can spider through them. The other stuff is just to make sure that the link is a real link and not some other strange crap

Comment: If you use selenium do you find the links then appear in output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get links from your html example:

```
tag = soup.findAll('link')

[i["href"] for i in tag]
```

Comment: What is that second line doing? Is that to just get the link?

Comment: It takes hrefs in links.

Comment: But for whatever reason I am not finding any links at all but I am certain there are ones....

Comment: If the html contains href inside `<link>`, the code I wrote finds it.